# Create a bitmap from an offscreen layout generated by Jetpack Compose

Tags: android

I would like to generate a bitmap from a view but using Jetpack Compose and the view has to be such that it is not attached to any window. There are posts on how to create offscreen views using the old view model (xml based) and even generate a bitmap from that. But I was not able to find any way of creating a view using Jetpack compose.

Ultimately a composable does get drawn to a canvas, but I am not aware of any way to access that canvas. Another issue I need to avoid is that newer versions of Android attempt to use hardware bitmaps and my experience with these hasn't been good when trying to generate them from a canvas.

Comment: Wrap the composable in a `ComposeView`, then use traditional `View` techniques on the `ComposeView`. In the end, everything in Compose UI runs through a `ComposeView` somewhere. For example, the `setContent()` extension function [for `ComponentActivity`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:activity/activity-compose/src/main/java/androidx/activity/compose/ComponentActivity.kt;l=48?q=activity.setContent%20compose&ss=androidx) uses `ComposeView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Bitmap takeScreenshot(Activity activity) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
            e.printStackTrace();
            return bitmap;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this work even if the Activity is not being shown?

Comment: I don't know, you can test it.

Comment: Sure but it's the key part of the question above "offscreen", hence why I asked.